# SSRS BIDS Tooltip text formatting

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, tooltip, expression

```
="Project: " + Fields!barname.Value + VbCrLf  + "Service: " + Fields!SERVICE.Value
```

Is it possible to make the above text BOLD when I hover over to display the tooltip using the expression language in BIDS, have tried html tags which do not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve what you want in SSRS out-of-the-box. The Tooltip is rendered in report as "Title" attribute for HTML element and it is not taking any formatting.

What you can do is writing some JavaScript code that will handle tooltip for you, hover attaching such a code is always "hacky". You can find sample solution of using JavaScript to control tooltip in SSRS here:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/d0bb5af6-ca4f-4b67-a0f0-2e2ea297e98c

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing "+" to "&", like this:

```
="Project: " & Fields!barname.Value & VbCrLf  & "Service: " & Fields!SERVICE.Value
```